# ¿Cómo seleccionar el ultimo array, si mi array principal cuenta que hay mas de 5 arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, woocommerce

Como ordeno para que en mis respuesta siempre el que tenga el numero de post mayor, se muestre primero en el array[0],

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este pequeño código para seleccionar el primer dato, pero habrán veces en la que el producto se habrá publicado mas de 10 veces, y quisiera que la recientemente añadida sea la que se muestre primero

`$query = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = ".$r->art_codigo.";");`
`$resultado = $query['data']->[0]->[post_id]`

Ahi es donde me gustaría ordenar, para que el ultimo array dentro de "data", sea el primero siempre,

Alguna función, para hacerlo cada vez que consulte la tabla de datos?

Comment: Agrega un orden en la instrucción SQL: `SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE ... ORDER BY meta_id DESC`, así te ordenará por el `meta_id`, poniendo primero el de mayor valor.

Comment: @A.Cedano me funciono correctamente, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega un `ORDER BY meta_id DESC` en la instrucción SQL, así te ordenará por el `meta_id`, poniendo primero el de mayor valor.

```
$query = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = {$r->art_codigo} ORDER BY meta_id DESC;"); 
$resultado = $query['data']->[0]->[post_id];
```

Para más detalles, [consulta el Manual de Referencia sobre `ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).